# How to use and pack folder packed in python packed .exe by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, flet

I have folder `languages` in my directory with `main.py` but when i did `flet pack main.py --add-data="languages:languages"` there was no error in terminal but when executing my `main.exe` there was error in flet window:

```
There was an error while processing your request: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\languages\\langname.txt'
```

I was able to fix it by just replacing `.txt` by adding `func` in code that return the same text as `.txt`, but there is other folder that I wanna use with not `.txt`, so for begin just folder with `.txt` is best.

I used:

```
flet pack main.py --add-data="languages:languages"
```

or

```
flet pack main.py --add-data "languages:languages"
```

or

```
flet pack main.py --add-data "languages;languages"
```

and

```
with open(fr'.\languages\{lang}.txt', 'r') as file:
```

or

```
with open(fr'{lang}.txt', 'r') as file:
```

or

```
with open(fr'languages\{lang}.txt', 'r') as file:
```

but all the time error the same.

Comment: `pyinstaller` doesn't create real `exe` but self-extracting `zip` file. If you need some files with resources then you have to use file `spec` to inform `pyinstaller` that it has to add your files to `.exe`. You can find details in documentation for `pyinstaller` - see [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html).  This problem was described in many questions on Stackoverflow - so you may also try to search answers on Stackoverlfow.

Comment: documentation for `pyinstaller` should also show how to create `/full/path/to/file.txt` because program may run in different folder and `relative path` may search your file in wrong place. You may use `os.getcwd()` to see `Current Working Directory`. And `os.dirlist()` to see what you have in this directory.